# need a better way add leading digits to int and return array of digits

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a modulus check which adds leading digits, lets say 0, to a seed int. I then need to return an array of digits in the array as I need to do a calculation on each digit to return a new whole number.

my code is as follows,

```
var seed = 1234;
var seedString = seed.ToString();
var test = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10 - seedString.Length; i++)
{
    test.Add(0);
}

var value = seed;
for(int i = 0; i < seedString.Length; i ++)
{

    test.Insert(10 - seedString.Length, value % 10);
    value = value / 10;

}
```

is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert your number to a 10-digit string, you can format the number using a [Custom Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) as follows:

```
string result = seed.ToString("0000000000");
// result == "0000001234"
```

See: [The "0" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0)

---

If you need a 10-element array consisting of the individual digits, try this:

```
int[] result = new int[10];
for (int value = seed, i = result.Length; value != 0; value /= 10)
{
    result[--i] = value % 10;
}
// result == new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

See also: [Fastest way to separate the digits of an int into an array in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613317/fastest-way-to-separate-the-digits-of-an-int-into-an-array-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int myNumber = 1234;  
string myStringNumber = myNumber.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
```

HTH

Comment: You can then use `.ToCharArray()` to get a character array. Subtracting `'0'` from each character should result in the int value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another shorthand way of getting the string representation would be

```
int num = 1234;
num.ToString("D10");
```